Windows 10 Wake on LAN over Ethernet, not Wifi?
I have an MSI GF65 Thin that lives in another room of the house.  Sometimes I need to access it from my office on the other side of the house, but it's asleep.

The laptop has WoL enabled in the BIOS.
The laptop it on wired ethernet, wifi is disabled
The NIC is a Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller, and does not have any options regarding WoL or the Magic Packet
I have been able to use WoL over wifi before, but I would prefer this machine to only be on wired ethernet.

Is there a way to get WoL to work on this machine without enabling wifi?

WoL is likely less reliable over Wifi than it is with ethernet, but its always a finicky thing in the best of cases. it does require power settings changes for the device however. check this article and see if it gets you going: https://www.howtogeek.com/764943/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-in-windows-10-and-11/

Thanks, I'm specifically trying to use it over Ethernet instead of wifi.  In my case, wifi is the only way it works.  But I'll check the article you linked, thanks. EDIT: My card has no Power Management tab, and no settings for WoL at all.  This is unfortunately why I'm stuck.

I'd probably go looking for another version of that driver, perhaps from MSI, instead of the windows update version.

Thanks @FrankThomas, I'm trying to download new drivers now from Realtek's site, but their captcha doesn't work.  I have absolutely entered it in correctly over and over again, but it just fails in an endless loop.  Apparently they have had captcha problems going back many years.  Terrible.

Do you need us to try to look up exactly which Realtek GbE controller model# your MSI GF65 Thin system uses and what that model of Realtek GbE controller is capable of, or is that something you can do for yourself?

The trouble is that it's not possible to download the driver from the realtek site due to their captcha not working, and I couldn't even find any reference to my model of laptop on MSI's site.  Seems maybe it's too old at this point?  So I'm a bit dead in the water with regards to a new driver.  =/

I have a Realtek RTL8111H wired ethernet NIC in a desktop that also appears in Windows as Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller. It has working WOL with the following settings:

WOL enabled in BIOS
Driver version 10.50.511.2021 from 2021-05-11 (rt640x64.sys), downloaded from my motherboard manufacturer's site
Device properties

Advanced

Shutdown Wake-On-Lan: disabled
Wake on Magic Packet: enabled
Wake on magic packet when system is in the S0ix power state: disabled
Wake on pattern match: disabled
WOL & Shutdown Link Speed: 10 Mbps First


Power Management

Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power: enabled
Allow this device to wake the computer: enabled
Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer: enabled





Maybe you can spot a difference between this and your system that helps narrow down the problem.



Thanks, unfortunately the difference is everything.  My controller doesn't have any settings at all related to WoL or magic packets.  In fact it has only a fraction of what you have under Advanced, and has no Power Management tab at all.

Right, so now we know a model name, driver version, date, filename, download source, and 9 settings that result in verified working WOL.

Will this driver from Asus work on an MSI laptop?

It might, if the Realtek NIC model is similar enough. If it were me I'd try it if I couldn't get downloads from Realtek's site to work, and it's simple to uninstall if it doesn't work. You could also use this version/date/filename info as a hint when trying to find a corresponding driver from MSI or a Google search.

I'll be damned, it worked!  I never would have thought to try an installer explicitly labeled as "Asus", but once I rebooted I have all the same setting you do, and WoL now works.  THANK YOU!!!

Glad it's working! I think Asus just wrapped an upstream Realtek installer that broadly applies to lots of their NIC models. I've seen other computer vendors like Lenovo and Dell do this too.
